# How can I get an xmlnode from xmlnodereader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I'm reading the icecat sheets as one giant xml document (1.7g) and i'm using xmlnodereader.

How do I read it node by node. I know, normally, you wouldn't do this but the structure looks like

```
<file attr=value>...</file>


<file attr=value>...</file>


<file attr=value>...</file>


<file attr=value>...</file>


<file attr=value>...</file>
```

here is some existing code for reference:

```
 foreach (BackgroundWorker worker in Pool)
            {
                if (worker.IsBusy)
                    continue;
                //read xmlnode and pass it to the worker

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using LINQ to XML if you can. You can use:

```
XElement element = XElement.Load(reader);
```

which will just load a single element from the reader, advancing it appropriate. It's really easy to do, and the LINQ to XML API is much nicer than the old DOM API.